# InflateException when trying to switch between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I've changed my android version in the middle of a project from 4.0.3 to 2.3.3
since then i can't move between my 2 activities, got the error:

```
05-26 15:04:12.050: E/AndroidRuntime(571): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.udios.sapool/com.udios.sapool.SignupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #199: Error inflating class Switch
```

I've already changed the minSdk to :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

is there anything else i forgot?
Thanks. udi

Comment: I'm guessing your custom View `Switch` is using an API 14 call that's not available in API 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SignupActivity Activity you are using [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) which is supported in **API Level 14**, not in **API Level 10**. see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html).

if you want to use Swicth in you Appiction then set **minSdkVersion** to **14**.as

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```